# echo items of array in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I Want to echo **distance value** item of this array

```
{"status":"Ok","rows":[{"elements":[{"status":"Ok","duration":{"value":39746,"text":"۱۱ ساعت ۲ دقیقه"},"distance":{"value":782370,"text":"۸۰۰ کیلومتر"}}]}],"origin_addresses":["34.446808,45.328753"],"destination_addresses":["32.656559,51.665333"]}
```

any one know how shoud i do this in laravel controller?

Comment: Is there always one distance key in the object? You only want to find the key distance and print it's value?

Comment: yes it has only one distance key in the object. i want to echo '782370'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**json_decode()** is answer your question

Distance param path :

```
json_decode($json)->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value
```